# Как сделать скругления блока?

Tags: html, css, vector

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такие волны сверху и снизу блока? В макете есть два ветора, когда наводишь на них показывает верхние и нижние волны.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Рисуются в фотошопе 2 волны, одна белая, другая светло-зеленая и накладываются

Comment: @Arcadiy спасибо. Я в файлах макета нашел 2 файла (добавил их сюда, 4-5 фото) видно это как раз этот же фон с этими волнами только оттенки другие, а на сайте оттенок одинаковый. Это изображения как-то наложить чтоб добиться такого цвета или что-то отдельно прописывать?

Answer (score 0):

Первым делом вы должны создать основной блок, а затем добавить сверху и снизу эти две волны, например, при помощи ::after и ::before.

```
.block::after, .block::before{
 height: 40px;
 width: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}

.block::before{
 background: url(img/up_wave.png);
}

.block::after{
 background: url(img/down_wave.png);
}
```

Comment: Или можно не идти сложным путем и просто в виде фона сделать эту картинку, которую вы приложили: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIpoZ.png. Там уже поставить отступ изнутри для этого же блока, чтобы элементы не касались волн.

Comment: @Endvine спасибо

Comment: @Jaspers, этот способ помог? Если да, то прошу отметить галкой, что он лучший.